Unity: Screen around game view goes black when entering play mode (happens on every project)

Here you can see the bug. Whenever I enter the play-mode on any of my Unity projects the screen around the game view goes black and I can't exit the play mode. I can only get back to editing if I completely close and then again open the project.
I searched the internet for the problem, but I didn't find any solution. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me :)

Your Preferences > Colors > Playmode tint is set to black
